# Why do I see two different ffmpeg binaries?

Tags: debian, automated-install, ffmpeg

On Debian Lenny I built my own ffmpeg. When i do ffmpeg --version inside of a sudo bash shell I get the version I just build. Outside of it I get the old version. When using sudo ffmpeg I get the new version.

How do I replace the old version of ffmpeg so my webapp can run the correct version of ffmpeg? I dont want to require sudo.

Comment: I solved it by using `whereis ffmpeg` then replacing one with the other

Comment: Good that you got it working, but it seems you fixed a symptom instead of the cause. Look deeper or it may bite you in the future. How about uninstalling the package the other binary came from, and fixing the difference in your PATH settings?

Comment: @Martin: see comment i left pjz. How do i fix the paths? i could try make install as a normal user but i dont know if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is almost certainly that your PATH is different when running sudo than not.  You'll likely need to either uninstall the old ffmpeg or replace its binaries in /usr/bin (or wherever) with your own.

Comment: Thats what i am thinking but HOW? Actually i just updated my server os and will be doing this again this week/ -edit- oops, this answer isnt new, it was the comment that was new